# How to find the interval between two dates and then return them with a function in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql and I want it to loop through all my entries and return the interval between 2 dates.
I have created the code below but everytime I execute the function I get a

`ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'contractDuration' at row 1`

My code has a loop going through all entries and for each one of them, it calculates the intervals and appends them in an array.

```
drop function if exists date_check;
delimiter //
create function date_check() 
returns int(50)
deterministic
begin

declare record_not_found int default 0;
declare dStart Date;
declare dEnd Date;
declare contractDuration int(50) default 0;
declare my_cursor cursor for select start_date, end_date from contract;
declare continue handler for not found set record_not_found = 1;

open my_cursor;
 allclients: loop
    fetch my_cursor into dStart, dEnd;
    select datediff(dEnd, dStart) into @f;
    if record_not_found then leave allclients;
    end if;
    set contractDuration = concat(contractDuration, @f, ", ");
 end loop allclients;
close my_cursor;

return substr(contractDuration,1,26);
end 
//

delimiter ;

select date_check();
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sql is for the storage and retrieval of relational data

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you simply run a query like this?

```
select group_concat(datediff(end_date, start_date) separator ', ') as diffs
from contract;
```

I don't see where the cursor provides any value for what you want to do.

I would note in your code that `contract_duration` is declared to be an integer, but you are trying to assign a string to it.